# Side navigation bar to fill up the content container

Tags: html, css

I am working on a new website layout. I want a layout where the header is at the top, there is content in the middle and a footer either at the bottom of the window, if the content is small, or the footer goes to the bottom of them content.

There is also going to be a sidebar on the left which should fill the space between the header and the footer, and grow to fill the space if content grows.

This is working fine in Google Chrome, but in Internet Explorer the side nav just fills the space that it's using and not filling the entire space between the header and the footer.

http://jsfiddle.net/ama4tyz2/embedded/result/ is a link to JS Fiddle that can be opened in Chrome so you can see what's wrong and the code.

Below is the code for my side bar CSS container as I think this is the problem. It looks like Internet Explorer is ignoring the min-height parameter.

```
nav.sideNav
{
    position: absolute;    
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    
    min-height: -moz-calc(100% - 160px);
    min-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 160px);
    min-height: -khtml-calc(100% - 160px);
    min-height: -o-calc(100% - 160px);
    min-height: -ms-calc(100% - 160px);
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a min-height: without any prefix. As far as i know newer versions of IE dont use -ms-

so keep what you have plus add:

```
min-height: calc(100% - 160px);
```

When you are adding CSS3 styles and needing to use the different browser prefixes you should also include a generic non prefixed style.

See here for fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5jmwd96e/embedded/result/